# Prove the following language is context-free:

Tags: context-free-grammar

This question is on a sample exam that our professor was too lazy to type up solutions to and I am stuck pretty bad. Thanks in advance for your help!

Prove that the following language is context-free `{x is an element of {a,b,c}* | the number of a's in x is greater than the number of b's or the number of c's in x}`

Comment: You might get a better response on Math.SE.

Comment: @KendallFrey I'll suggest [CSTheory](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/) :)

Comment: @bludger No, not [cstheory.se], which is for research-level questions only. This topic is appropriate for [cs.se], though we'd appreciate to see a little effort from the asker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> {x is an element of {a,b,c}* | the number of a's in x is greater than the number of b's or the number of c's in x}

This can be interpreted two ways:

1. The number of `a`'s is greater than (the number of `b`'s plus the number of `c`'s)
2. (The number of `a`'s is greater than the number of `b`'s) or (the number of `a`'s is greater than the number of `c`'s).

Hints for 1: A PDA could work as follows. If the stack is empty and you see an `a` on the input, then add an `a` to the stack. If the stack is empty and you see a `b` or a `c` on the input, add a `b` to the stack. If the top-most stack symbol is a `b` and you see an `a` on the input, remove a `b` from the stack. If the top-most stack symbol is a `b` and you see a `b` or a `c` on the input, add another `b` to the stack. If the top-most stack symbol is an `a` and you see an `a` on the input, add another `a` to the stack. If the top-most stack symbol is an `a` and you see a `b` or a `c` on the input, remove an `a` from the stack. Now simply produce an argument that such a PDA will have (1) an empty stack if the number of `a`'s is equal to the sum of the numbers of `b`'s and `c`'s; (2) an `a` on top of the stack if it saw more `a`'s than it saw either `b`'s or `c`'s (combined); (3) a `b` on top of the stack if it saw fewer `a`'s than it saw either `b`'s or `c`'s (combined).

Hints for 2: First, construct a PDA accepting any string of `a`'s, `b`'s, and `c`'s which has more `a`'s than `b`'s, ignoring any `c`'s (the PDA described above in Hints for 1 can be easily modified to ignore `c`'s). Then, construct a PDA accepting any string of `a`'s, `b`'s, and `c`'s  which has more `a`'s than `c`'s, ignoring any `b`'s (similar to the one you just built). Finally, demonstrate that the language you are trying to prove context-free is the union of the languages accepted by these automata; a simple argument should suffice. Since context-free languages are closed under union, this demonstrates the claim, i.e., that the language you set out to prove context-free is, indeed, context-free.

Please feel free to request further clarification. Also, check out the new site for questions like this: https://cs.stackexchange.com/. You might receive even better answers on future questions at that site.

Answer (score -2):

The task is to show that the language can be generated by a context-free grammar.

some hints:

```
A -> aabAc | B
B -> B|epsilon
```